# Consulta SQL - Count con fecha

Tags: mysql, sql

Hola buenas tengo un problema con una consulta en bdd(sql) y es la siguiente: como mostrar cuantas veces desde la fecha de nacimiento(fecha X) hasta hoy(sysdate), ha caído sábado(día x de la semana)., de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: qué has intentado?

Comment: Copia la query que estás usando para que te podamos ver qué te falta

Comment: Seria bueno que colocaras el query que tienes  para ver que estas haciendo. Ahora tienes que hacerlo a fuerzas desde mysql o puedes trabajarlo desde otro lenguaje como por ejemplo PHP

Answer (score 0):

Buenas tardes,

podrías utilizar una función para calcular el número de días y a partir de ahí utilizar estructuras de control de flujo para ver, en función del día de la semana que deseas saber (del 1 al 7 en MySQL comenzando en domingo) y dos fechas concretas:

```
    CREATE FUNCTION howmanydays(dayselected integer, startdate date, enddate date) RETURNS integer
        DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN
            DECLARE startdayofweek integer;
            DECLARE enddayofweek integer;
            DECLARE numberdays integer;
            DECLARE numberweeks integer;
            DECLARE restdays integer;
            DECLARE numberdaysofweek integer;
            IF dayselected BETWEEN 1 AND 7 THEN
                    SET startdayofweek = DAYOFWEEK(startdate);
                    SET enddayofweek = DAYOFWEEK(enddate);
                    SET numberdays = FLOOR(DATEDIFF(enddate,startdate));
                    SET numberweeks = FLOOR(numberdays/7);
                    SET restdays = numberdays%7;
                    SET numberdaysofweek = numberweeks;
                    IF enddayofweek > startdayofweek THEN
                            IF dayselected BETWEEN startdayofweek AND enddayofweek THEN
                            SET numberdaysofweek = numberdaysofweek + 1;
                            END IF;
                    ELSE
                            IF dayselected BETWEEN startdayofweek and 7 OR dayselected BETWEEN 1 and enddayofweek THEN
                            SET numberdaysofweek = numberdaysofweek + 1;
                            END IF; 
                    END IF;
            ELSE
                    SET numberdaysofweek = -1;
            END IF;
            RETURN numberdaysofweek;
    END;//
```

He utilizado estas sentencias para probarlo:

```
    SELECT howmanydays(1,'2017-03-09','2017-03-25');//
    SELECT howmanydays(6,'2017-03-09','2017-03-25');//
    SELECT howmanydays(2,'2017-03-09','2017-03-27');//
    SELECT howmanydays(4,'2017-03-09','2017-03-27');//
    SELECT howmanydays(7,'2016-12-29','2016-12-31');//
    SELECT howmanydays(8,'2011-12-31','2011-12-29');//
```

Answer (score -1):

A ver si esto te ayuda: utiliza `DATENAME` o `DATEPART`:

```
SELECT DATENAME(dw,GETDATE()) -- Viernes
SELECT DATEPART(dw,GETDATE()) -- 6
```

Posteriormente puedes hacer el `COUNT()`.

Comment: Esto no contesta la pregunta.

Comment: Cualquier respuesta que encamine al los lectores en la dirección correcta ayudara siempre y cuando menciones limitaciones, supuestos, o simplificaciones en tu respuesta. - http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer